# Can't compare two ranges

Tags: c++, c++20

Can't figure out why `std::ranges::equal` in the code below does not compile:

```
struct A { int x; };

using Map = std::map<int, A>;

void some_func()
{
    std::vector<A> v{ {0}, {1}, {2}, {3} };
    
    auto v2m = [](const A& a) { return std::pair<int, A>(a.x, a); };

    const auto actual = std::ranges::single_view(v[2]) | std::views::transform(v2m);

    Map expected{ {v[2].x, v[2]} };

    //Does not compile.
    bool equals = std::ranges::equal(actual, expected);
}
```

The compiler errors with MSVC are:

```
error C2672: 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found
error C7602: 'std::ranges::_Equal_fn::operator ()': the associated constraints are not satisfied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 1: `A` isn't comparable, so you cannot compare it using `std::ranges::equal` with the default predicate. Solution:

```
struct A {
    int x;
    friend auto operator<=>(const A&, const A&) = default;
};
```

Problem 2: Your transform function produces `std::pair<int, A>` which doesn't match with the elements of map which are `std::pair<const int, A>`. Solution: use `std::pair<const int, A>` (or just `Map::value_type` so that there's less room for mistakes).

Comment: TIL, `pair<T, U>` is not comparable to `pair<T const, U>` even when it's comparable itself (unlike `tuple`).